# is it possible to force regex to match only one group while using the global flag?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I am testing the following the  regex  `\b\w+123\b` on regex101.com
[image]

As you can see on the screenshot it matches as many words as it is capable since the multiline and global flags are on. 
But what if I wanted to **force it to stop after it matches the first occurrence:`hehe123sada123123`** , while I'm using those two flags. 
I've tried to capture it as a group and then apply a lazy quantifier next to it:
[image]

Doesn't work...

  Maybe using {1}? [image]

Neither...

Text: 
hehe123sada123123
asdsadas13423 asdsadas1563 hehe123
asdsadas123 asdsadas123
asdsk0adas123 asdsadas123 asdsadas
asdsadasfr5 asdsa345das123 sdsfdeadas123 sdsfdeadas123 sdsfdeadas123

Comment: please add source sting as text

Comment: i am not quite sure what you try to do. with `(\b\w+123\b)(.*)` or `(\b\w+123\b)([\s\S]*)` you could get the first and the rest.

Comment: (\b\w+123\b)(.*) gives me the first match on each line, but I want only one match on the entire text

Comment: I want hehe123sada123123 to be the only one green highlighted

Comment: so please try `(\b\w+123\b)([\s\S]*)` and `^[^\n]?(\b\w+123\b)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[^\n]?(\b\w+123\b)
```

matches only the first inside of

```
hehe123sada123123 asdsadas13423 asdsadas1563 hehe123 asdsadas123 asdsadas123 asdsk0adas123 asdsadas123 asdsadas asdsadasfr5 asdsa345das123 sdsfdeadas123 sdsfdeadas123 sdsfdeadas123
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSaxv.jpg

Comment: what does ^[^\n]? mean? and why does it go on the front?

Comment: `[^abc]` Matches any other character `^` Matches the position at the beginning of the line `?` is non greedy